# Adding new property to Ext JS Grid column

Tags: javascript, extjs, sencha-touch, extjs6, extjs6-classic

Can I add a new unique property to `gridcolumn` in Ext JS? I want to use that property in some other place

```
{
    xtype: 'gridcolumn',
    dataIndex: 'startupPercent',
    sortable: true,
    'property': 'value', // so that i can access it later
    text: 'StartUp%'
}
```

Comment: Yes, you can do that.

Comment: I did, but on headerClick event, i can't get the assigned property and values @EvanTrimboli

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Can I add a new unique property to gridcolumn

Yes you can and you use that property other place.

In this **[FIDDLE](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/2gag)**, I have created a demo provide a custom config and get on header click. I hope this will help/guide you to achieve your requirement.

**CODE SNIPPET**

```
Ext.application({
    name: 'Fiddle',

    launch: function () {
        Ext.create('Ext.grid.Panel', {
            title: 'Demo',
            store: {
                data: [{
                    name: 'Lisa',
                    email: 'lisa@simpsons.com',
                    phone: '555-111-1224'
                }, {
                    name: 'Bart',
                    email: 'bart@simpsons.com',
                    phone: '555-222-1234'
                }, {
                    name: 'Homer',
                    email: 'homer@simpsons.com',
                    phone: '555-222-1244'
                }, {
                    name: 'Marge',
                    email: 'marge@simpsons.com',
                    phone: '555-222-1254'
                }]
            },
            columns: [{
                text: 'Name',
                dataIndex: 'name',
                isName: true
            }, {
                text: 'Email',
                dataIndex: 'email',
                flex: 1
            }, {
                text: 'Phone',
                dataIndex: 'phone'
            }],
            height: 200,
            renderTo: Ext.getBody(),
            listeners: {
                headerclick: function (ct, column, e, t, eOpts) {
                    if (column.isName) {
                        console.log(column.isName);
                    }
                }
            }
        });
    }
});
```